# Coffeescript invalid syntax

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Thoughts on why the following is invalid syntactically?

```
@foo(@bar('/test', {
      password
      username
      _method: 'GET'
    }
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the indentation.

The second parenthesis couldn't be read properly.
If you make an indent explicitly for it, it work.

```
@foo(
  @bar('/test', {
      password
      username
      _method: 'GET'
    }
  )
)
```

Or remove indentation of the closing parenthesis.

```
@foo(@bar('/test', {
    password
    username
    _method: 'GET'
  }
))
```

both of them works as

```
this.foo(this.bar('/test', {
  password: password,
  username: username,
  _method: 'GET'
}));
```